# How to set nano up for git commit messages with line length limits

Tags: git, nano

I use nano for git commit messages. Short summary (<=50 chars) plus a new line before the description is relatively straightforward to stick to. However, when it comes to wrapping at 72 chars in the description body I just go off what seems to look right, making for inconsistent logs.

In Vagrantfiles I've seen this sort of thing to tell the editor what to do for vi/vim:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

Is there something like that for nano, and a template somewhere for git commit, that means I can ensure that nano would be set up for the correct line wrapping when in the context of a git commit message?

Comment: export `GIT_EDITOR='nano -r 72'`

Comment: @Leon bingo! I didn't clock that in the man page, was focusing on softwraps. Can also do `git config --global core.editor "nano -r 72"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nano supports the passing of command line arguments when starting it.

This can be leveraged as part of the git editor config setting.

`git config --global core.editor "nano -r 72"`

Or:

`export GIT_EDITOR='nano -r 72'`

Comment: I found that in order to apply the configured word wrapping you'll need to press `ESC` followed by `L` once nano has opened.

Comment: For nano v4.0 and later, you may want to also add `-b` option.

Comment: Regarding @JamesFrost comment: Also consider `set breaklonglines` in .nanorc file.
"Since version 4.0, nano by default: • does not automatically hard-wrap lines that become overlong [...] To get the old, Pico behavior back, you can use set breaklonglines" [...]
(See https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

A very detailed tutorial (with further information) on how to set line wrapping for nano (in general, not only in the context of git) can be found at: https://croccifix.io/gnu-nano. 
Essentially you only have to comment out '*nowrap*' and add or change '*set fill*' to
'*set fill 72*' in nanorc.

In a terminal (I've tried it on a MAC):

```
cd /etc
sudo nano nanorc
#set nowrap
set fill 72
```